# Android add my application intent to edittext menu options

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to add a option to my app after select,copy,copy all, paste of menu items of edit text. I have to add intent action in that menu so that when user click the option it will trigger to my application

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: have you ever figured that out? i need to do the same thing exactly but so far came up with nothing

Answer (score 0):

ts as simple as that..

On click event of that menu item handle event..
and define intent, also define its action and your application class,then StartActivity or startActivity for result...

Thanks
Rakesh

Comment: Hi rakesh,
Thanks for reply but this is not i was looking for. I need to add my application link below with Android OS's edit,copy,paste.